# How to prevent potential XSS

Tags: php, browser, xss, shared-libraries

I was reading about XSS and I found out that checking IP and user-agent is a good way to prevent cookie stealing. I tested that on SO and I found out SO doesn't log out people after changing their IP or user-agent but when I copied **ALL** headers and send them to SO using another program, it sent me out. How it can detect that something is different when IP and user agent are not important and all http headers are the same?

Comment: The IP address of a mobile user can change during a session just because they drive down the street.  I'm not sure I would recommend using that as a factor in preventing session hijacking.  If you have a reliable ISP lookup database, changing ISP could be considered a better indication, but even so, someone taking their iPhone from the office down to Starbucks could trigger that condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SE for example uses a more way auth. SE saves a token like a cookie as a offline data on a subdomain and sends that to the server where the data are verified on some way. Than you get a temporal token that is send to the login Site and you will been logged in.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I didn't get it. When All headers are the same as original, How it can detect that I'm someone else?

Comment: It's possible that other checks are done like e.g. a second hidden token. I mean I can see that while the login process a token is read out with a function but I cannot repreduce that. Not sure why so I'm not able to *steal* that session. But it's anyway a better idea to try to prevent any xss thrue parsing everything which comes from the web.